# ADOdb Library for PHP, ADODB error handler, get the filename, line where error occurs

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1064, adodb-php

I use `ADOdb Library for PHP` and I would like when I have an error in `MYSQL` like syntax error `INSER INTO` or `DUPLICATE ENTRY IN INSERT INTO` and the `ADODB_Error_Handler($dbms, $fn, $errno, $errmsg, $p1, $p2, &$thisConnection)` is activated to get the name of the file and the line  where the error occurs. For the time being I get the error..

How can I fix it ?

Comment: i'd suggest to put all your call inside a try/catch and then print the filename (or log it to file/db)

Comment: yeah can be an option but would helpful to do it using ADODdb error handler. I have a lot of files(more than 50) to try/catch so I believe ADODB error handler is the suggested option.

Comment: 50 or five thousand is the correct mode to manage errors (for me at least), that said you can see if the page called has got any kind of info from the caller, you can try to give the caller name file as parameter and then print it.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve and how you're attempting to do it is not very clear from your question. Maybe you could post a code snippet to reproduce the problem, and explain what you expect to get vs what adodb actually does.